# Route incoming and outgoing on same interface

Tags: firewall, networkmanager, network-interface

My router currently provides the NAT to all the PCs and the Ubuntu desktop (with some server functions) in the network. I want to use the Ubuntu system as a proper firewall, but it only has one Ethernet interface. As such, I envision the following to get it running:

```
      Ubuntu/firewall     router/WAN          DHCP
IP    192.168.1.1         192.168.1.10        192.168.1.*
GW    192.168.1.10        WAN IP              192.168.1.1
```

- Can I expect everything to work fine if I statically configure my Ubuntu system and router as I described?
- Will it be fine to use the single physical interface to handle `INPUT` and `FORWARD`? Do I need to do things like create virtual interfaces?

Comment: I expect this won't work, I think that the linux system will send ICMP redirects instead of NATing connections from the local network that want to go to the internet. You will need separate interfaces; VLANs will work fine but then you will need a switch that supports tagged VLANs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's ICMP redirects? AFAIK ICMP is to do with `ping`, but why would Linux redirect the packets as ICMP?

Comment: ICMP is used for much more than simple ping tests. If a client uses system A as its gateway to reach host X, but system A knows that host X is reachable through system B on the same network as the client, then system A will use ICMP redirect to tell the client to send its packets to system B instead of system A.

Comment: @wurtel, I see. That is to say, it won't go through the firewall filters I will've setup in the Linux system.

Comment: @wurtel Is there no way to disable ICMP redirects?

Comment: not that I know of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accomplished what I've described in the question. Here's the Ubuntu configuration that allowed me to do so:

```
$ sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
```

(Actually `br0` in my files, from bridging VM to physical LAN, but I've replaced them with more generic `eth0`)

```
$ sudoedit /etc/sysctl.conf

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Basically, `sysctl.conf`'s packet forwarding configuration is what, I believe, allowed my setup to work.

I've confirmed that the setup indeed worked by seeing `traceroute`s going through `192.168.0.10` before `192.168.0.1` and the firewall rules configured on Ubuntu actually filtered the traffic as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use two separate networks? It is easy to add two IPs of different networks with only one card (eth0, eth0:1, eth0:2, etc...).

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1/24
ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.10.1/24
```

This way all computers will be inside a network without acces to the Internet having to be routed through the Ubuntu FW which is the one that knows how to transfer communication from one network to the other.

Comment: The router is between the Ubuntu system and the rest of the PCs. Will it bridge without issues?

Comment: You'll need to set the router up and check what you can do with it, but it will most probably allow you to create two separated networks and route between them (that's what routers are for). I don't know if those that ISPs install are limited or not (I don't even know if your router is of that kind or you bought one by yourself). Mine is a Buffalo and it allows all kind of stuff like VPNs, VLANs, etc... and of course create two networks and route between them.

Comment: I've got `iface br0 inet dhcp` with `bridge_ports eth0`; can you edit your answer to add how statically add `eth0:0` to it?

Comment: If your router is configured to access the internet then you may not have to do anything on it (if ports are being used in switching mode) you will only need to add a new IP to your FW and configure FW, routing and NAT. In your client machines just change the IPs for those of the new network and change the routing so that the GW for those machines is the FW.

Comment: Eh, just tried it without touching the router. `HOST UNREACHABLE`. Gonna try with adding network to it's routes in a bit,

Comment: Adding routes to router did not help.

Comment: When you got the HOST UNREACHABLE (I assume your router is in the first state -no new configuration-) what did you do? what was your setup? post origin and destination IPs, what command did you use? what where your routes?.

Comment: Router static `192.168.0.1/24`. Ubuntu DHCP `eth0 192.168.0.10/24`, static `eth0:0 172.16.0.1/12`. Windows (hatefully) client static `172.16.0.10/12`, GW `172.16.0.1`. Ping `HOST UNREACHABLE`.

Comment: ping what? 172.16.0.1, 192.168.0.10, or the internet?

Comment: `ping 172.16.0.1`.

Comment: Try to set your router in switching mode in the ports where the windows/ubuntu machine are. Other option is creating two VLANs. By the way, be sure you don't have your FW running at this stage (you should disconect from the internet before shutting down the FW) to be sure no FW rule is messing communications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30007/discussion-between-oxwivi-and-yomismo).